# what command i have to use to clear rexster graph from terminal?

Tags: python-2.7, titan, rexster

I know how to clear graph data data with python bulbs. We clear the graph data with

```
'g.clear()'
```

but i want to clear graph from terminal

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear about whether you're asking for a BASH command to delete all graph data, or if you're asking for the rexster-console command to clear a graph. I'm making a guess you mean the rexster-console:

```
g.V().remove()
```

Should do the trick. You will iterate over all vertices and remove them, which should also remove all the edges between them. Depending on how large your dataset is, this may take a long time.